# Need any or IBMi API to validate address existence

Tags: ibm-midrange, rpgle

I am in search of an IBMi API that could validate existence of an address, I am not sure if there is any native IBMi API that can do this, since all my search has exhausted.

I tried looking at validateaddress api provided by google, but am not sure if that can be invoked from an IBMi SQLRPGLE program. (I am okay if anyone could point me in the direction to integrate this service with my IBMi program).

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/address-validation/demo

I am open to any thoughts/ suggestions on this topic.

Comment: Lots of articles around consuming Web APIs from RPG IV.  Do some research, pick your tooling (SQL, HTTP API, Bvstools, ...  The version of IBM i you are working with will matter.)  and if you have problems ask a specific question.

Comment: @Charles,  I have a bunch of addresses kept in PF and the client wants them to be geo validated like whether they exist or not.  Could you be able to list out few names for free APIs that can help validate address with geo location, mostly any accurate API that i have encountered is pay per use basis.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know what kind of API Google exposes. Maybe you want to have a look at [this IT Jungle Article](https://www.itjungle.com/2017/09/18/guru-consuming-rest-web-service-using-sql-get/) about how to use SQL to connect to an API service for a start.

Comment: "Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the external resource is unreachable or goes permanently offline. Links to other websites should always be helpful, but avoid making it necessary to click on them as much as possible." 
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer